# How to convert dataframe columns with list of values into rows in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe like this"

```
   A       B        C
0  [X]     [1]  [aa, bb, cc]
1  [Y]     [2]  [xx, yy]
```

i want to change it to:

```
   A       B        C
0  X       1        aa
1  X       1        bb
2  X       1        cc
3  Y       2        xx
4  Y       2        yy
```

Comment: the [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method is the answer `df.explode(df.columns.to_list())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use explode method chained like this,

```
df.explode('A').explode('B').explode('C').reset_index(drop=True)


   A  B   C
0  X  1  aa
1  X  1  bb
2  X  1  cc
3  Y  2  xx
4  Y  2  yy
```

Alternatively, you can apply `pd.Series.explode` on the dataframe like this,

```
df.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)
```

In pandas [1.3+](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html#reshaping) you can use a list of columns to explode on,

So the code will look like,

```
df.explode(['A', 'B', 'C']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Sreeram. Appreciate your quick help.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```py
df.explode(df.columns.to_list())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.explode('C').explode(['A', 'B'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```